# Download Bootstrap's less file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've used [Bootstrap's customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page to customize the colors etc.

Is it possible to download the .less file now, so I can customize it further when required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually no. Enter your custom LESS definitions and colors and press the "compile and download" button at the bottom of the webpage. The webpage will compile your custom definitions to a`.zip`-file containing a bootstrap-theme.css/bootstrap-theme.min.css. This compilation does not contain the `.less` files you are looking for.

If you want to customize the `.less` source files of Bootstrap manually, you will have to download [Bootstrap Source Code](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Comment: thanks. I've done that. Where can find the less files? inside the `less` folder?

Comment: Yes you will find the `less` files in that folder.